# CI/CD for Bitbucket to Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I already had a Nodejs App with MongoDB deployed on Azure VM. (I followed the [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oykl1Ih9pMg))

Currently, I manually update the branch using
`git pull` and then `pm2 restart app.ts`.

How do I implement CI/CD from the bitbucket to trigger my VM for automated update?

Comment: Do you have Bitbucket Pipelines YAML? There are multiple ways to accomplish that actually. Where did you stuck ?

Comment: I am not sure which Bitbucket YAML starter template to use. Is it "Deploy Node.js app to Azure"? Would like to know what is the method for my case?

Comment: If you have only one server and not planning to scale it, you can add it as `runner` to pipelines. Also, you can use something like `ansible`. First, look at the general structure, then identify your priorities and after that come up with a method that meets your needs.

Comment: might be a very different question, but I hope you know why you want to host a NodeJS app yourself on IaaS instead of using something like AppService and CosmosDB (with Mongo API)?

Comment: @silent because the app is already hosted on the VM. Ideally, we do not want to re-host it somewhere else. So, in this case, I am wondering the best way to implement CI/CD? Because from my study, the app others implement CI/CD is mostly hosted on AppService...

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.